# Bridge Text Effect in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Want to create a `Bridge Text Effect` like below, i tried using arctext but it doesnt help. I tried to google id but it doesnt understand Bridge text Shapes.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var x = canvas.width / 2;
      var y = canvas.height / 2;

      context.font = '30pt Calibri';
      // textAlign aligns text horizontally relative to placement
      context.textAlign = 'center';
      // textBaseline aligns text vertically relative to font style
      context.textBaseline = 'middle';
      context.fillStyle = 'blue';
      context.fillText('BRIDGE TEXT', x, y);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do this with plain canvas. You will either need to draw each vertical line in "slices" with varying heights or do a pixel displacement using an off-screen canvas (in both cases).

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware The Text would be user generated so will that matter ? I dont understand what do you mean by Pixel displacement, please advise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Displacement

There are at least two ways you can achieve a curved text effect - both share the same principle of displacement of pixels (moving them out of position relative to their real position), it's just a matter of which method we use to do this.

In the following demo I will use simple slicing using the internal `drawImage` method. Optional we could have iterated the pixel buffer and manually projected the pixels but for cases such as this it's simpler to use slicing IMO and we get anti-aliasing for free.

## Example + demo

Here is a full example (see demo for sliders and custom text) on one way of doing this:

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/0btz7a1g/)**

The result will be:

[image: Bridge example]

```
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'), /// get canvas
    font = '64px impact',        /// define font
    w = demo.width,              /// cache width and height
    h = demo.height,
    curve,                       /// curve for our text
    offsetY,                     /// offset from top (see note)
    bottom,                      /// bottom origin
    textHeight,                  /// height of text
    angleSteps = 180 / w,        /// angle steps per pixel
    i = w,                       /// counter (for x)
    y,
    os = document.createElement('canvas'), /// off-screen canvas
    octx = os.getContext('2d');

/// set off-screen canvas same size as our demo canavs
os.width = w;
os.height = h;

/// prep text for off-screen canvas
octx.font = font;
octx.textBaseline = 'top';
octx.textAlign = 'center';

/// main render function
function renderBridgeText() {

    /// snipped... get various data (see demo for detail)

    /// clear canvases
    octx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    /// draw the text (see demo for details)    
    octx.fillText(iText.value, w * 0.5, 0);

    /// slide and dice (MAIN)
    i = w;
    while (i--) {
        /// calc distance based on curve (=radius) and x position
        y = bottom - curve * Math.sin(i * angleSteps * Math.PI / 180);

        /// draw the slice for this vertical line
        ctx.drawImage(os, i, offsetY, 1, textHeight,
                          i, offsetY, 1, y);
    }
}
```

Note on offset: offset can be many things - in this demo I let it be the top source of the text to "correct" the curving a little as texts aren't drawn at the very top (due to various glyph geometry which I'm not gonna into here) - you will see this clearly between Chrome and Firefox as the text is rendered differently.

The demo let you change text and adjust a few parameters so you can see what effect they have on the text.

## How it works

The width is divided first on number of pixels we want to displace on the x axis. This gives us the delta angle we need to use for each pixel step.

Then we calculate a basic distance based on angle for y-axis using sinus using curve as radius. As the delta angle now corresponds to an angle from 0 to 180 based on x position this will gives us a nice curve matching the text width which is drawn in center.

This value we subtract from bottom to get the y position for the bottom of text.

Then we pick a normal sized slice from the source, one pixel thick, and we scale it to destination based on the y value. This does the trick.