# Text with arc direction in Canvas, but letters should keep vertical

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

This is what I'm trying to make:

[image] [image]

Closer I got was bridge text like this example, but it uses a Top baseline for the bridge and I'm not sure how to addapt it to my needs:

[Bridge Text Effect in HTML5 Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460533/bridge-text-effect-in-html5-canvas)

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0btz7a1g/

```js
/// (c) Ken Fyrstenberg Nilsen, Abidas Software .com
/// License: CC-Attribute

var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
    font = '64px impact',
    w = demo.width,
    h = demo.height,
    curve,
    offsetY,
    bottom,
    textHeight,
    isTri = false,
    dltY,
    angleSteps = 180 / w,
    i = w,
    y,
    os = document.createElement('canvas'),
    octx = os.getContext('2d');

os.width = w;
os.height = h;

octx.font = font;
octx.textBaseline = 'top';
octx.textAlign = 'center';

function renderBridgeText() {

    curve = parseInt(iCurve.value, 10);
    offsetY = parseInt(iOffset.value, 10);
    textHeight = parseInt(iHeight.value, 10);
    bottom = parseInt(iBottom.value, 10);
    isTri = iTriangle.checked;

    vCurve.innerHTML = curve;
    vOffset.innerHTML = offsetY;
    vHeight.innerHTML = textHeight;
    vBottom.innerHTML = bottom;

    octx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    octx.fillText(iText.value.toUpperCase(), w * 0.5, 0);

    /// slide and dice
    i = w;
    dltY = curve / textHeight;
    y = 0;
    while (i--) {
        if (isTri) {
            y += dltY;
            if (i === (w * 0.5)|0) dltY = -dltY;
        } else {
            y = bottom - curve * Math.sin(i * angleSteps * Math.PI / 180);
        }
        ctx.drawImage(os, i, 0, 1, textHeight,
        i, h * 0.5 - offsetY / textHeight * y, 1, y);
    }
}

iCurve.onchange = iOffset.onchange = iHeight.onchange = iBottom.onchange = iText.onkeyup = iTriangle.onchange = renderBridgeText;

renderBridgeText()
```

```css
span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:70px;
    text-align:right;
    font:12px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=demo width=400 height=300></canvas>
<br>
    <span>Curve:</span>
<input id="iCurve" type="range" min=0 max=200 value=110>
<span id="vCurve">110</span>
    <br><span>OffsetY:</span>
<input id="iOffset" type="range" min=0 max=100 value=4>
<span id="vOffset">0</span>
    <br><span>Text height:</span>
<input id="iHeight" type="range" min=0 max=200 value=64>
<span id="vHeight">64</span>
    <br><span>Bottom:</span>
<input id="iBottom" type="range" min=0 max=200 value=200>
<span id="vBottom">200</span>
    <br><span>Triangle:</span>
    <input id="iTriangle" type="checkbox">
<br><span>Text:</span>
<input id="iText" type="text" value="BRIDGE TEXT">
```

Is there any way to arc text while keeping each letter vertical like in the images?

Comment: Please add your code to your question, don't work around the rules by pretending the word "Fiddle" is code. Read the "*[mcve]*" guidance to see what we expect.

Comment: Yes. Do the same thing the code you link to does. Draw the text, slice it into vertical strips, reposition each slice in an arc.

Comment: @Ouroborus that's what I'been trying to do all day, trying to addapt that example to my needs.

Comment: @DavidThomas I had added another link to a stack overflow post with all the code. If i had my own code with valid changes I would have added that here. But anyway, I understand the rule, I just think it makes no sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool works by drawing the text normally, slicing it into 1px wide vertical strips, then redrawing those strips with vertical scaling and offset. Knowing how [`.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) functions helps a lot in making this possible. Changing this algorithm to your needs is a matter of changing how the scaling and offset are calculated.

Two parameters are calculated for each strip: Offset and height. `y` controls the arc but is used directly to set the target height. `h * 0.5 - offsetY / textHeight * y` scales and offsets `y` to produce the offset.

Since `y` is derived almost directly from `sin()`, we can use that as the offset instead. The height would remain fixed so we use `textHeight` for that.

Changing

```
ctx.drawImage(os, i, 0, 1, textHeight,
                  i, h * 0.5 - offsetY / textHeight * y, 1, y);
```

to

```
ctx.drawImage(os, i, 0, 1, textHeight,
                  i, y, 1, textHeight);
```

does the trick.

This is the minimum change necessary. I'll leave it as an exercise for yourself as to how to further clean up the code.